# How do I write a sql query to "expand" a table that currently has a field to denote repeating records?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need a table that contains a record for every month instead of a table that has a repeat count field.

My data currently looks like this:

```
Property       Item        Month          Repeat_Count      Amount
------------------------------------------------------------------
A              Rent        1/1/2016        1                100
A              Rent        2/1/2016        1                105
A              Rent        3/1/2016        3                110
A              Rent        6/1/2016        1                115
A              Rent        7/1/2016        6                120
A              Rent        1/1/2017        1                125
```

And I want it to look like this:

```
Property   Item      Month         Amount
-----------------------------------------
A          Rent      1/1/2016      100
A          Rent      2/1/2016      105
A          Rent      3/1/2016      110
A          Rent      4/1/2016      110
A          Rent      5/1/2016      110
A          Rent      6/1/2016      115
A          Rent      7/1/2016      120
A          Rent      8/1/2016      120
A          Rent      9/1/2016      120
A          Rent      10/1/2016     120
A          Rent      11/1/2016     120
A          Rent      12/1/2016     120
A          Rent      1/1/2017      125
```

Hope I did a good job explaining this one, thanks!

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.  The best way depends on the database.

Comment: Hi and welcome to stack overflow. here we expect you to have a go at it yourself first... at least to go googling for ideas that might work... then show us what you tried.

Comment: I guess that is my issue - I have SQL experience, but with simple queries and joins - I have never come across something like this where I have to show the data a completely different way.  Is there a specific command I should try to research?

Comment: Why are you keeping a *repeat count* instead of a row for each month (which would be the proper way to do it)? You wouldn't have this trouble trying to artificially create rows if the rows were actually there.

Comment: Hi Turophile, I'm curious to know how you formatted my data in that way?  I apologize, but could not figure out how to do that!  Thanks

Comment: @JasonC: I'm not Turophile, but all you need to do in the editor is select the relevant portion of the text and then press the `{}` button.

Comment: Hi Ken,  that is exactly my problem - this is how the data already looks in the table, and I have to write a query to add records to show the expanded records.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the formatting help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use a [table of numbers](http://web.archive.org/web/20150411042510/http://web.archive.org/web/20150411042510/http://sqlserver2000.databases.aspfaq.com/why-should-i-consider-using-an-auxiliary-numbers-table.html) and `CROSS APPLY`.

Table of numbers is simply a table that has one column with integer numbers from 1 to some large enough number, say, 100,000. I personally use table with 100K numbers. Aaron Bertrand wrote a [good article](http://sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-1) explaining how to generate such table.

**Sample data**

```
DECLARE @T TABLE ([Property] varchar(50), [Item] varchar(50), [Month] datetime, [Repeat_Count] int, [Amount] int);

INSERT INTO @T ([Property], [Item], [Month], [Repeat_Count], [Amount]) VALUES
('A', 'Rent', '2016-01-01 00:00:00', 1, 100),
('A', 'Rent', '2016-02-01 00:00:00', 1, 105),
('A', 'Rent', '2016-03-01 00:00:00', 3, 110),
('A', 'Rent', '2016-06-01 00:00:00', 1, 115),
('A', 'Rent', '2016-07-01 00:00:00', 6, 120),
('A', 'Rent', '2017-01-01 00:00:00', 1, 125);
```

**Query**

```
SELECT *
FROM
    @T AS T
    CROSS APPLY
    (
        SELECT
            DATEADD(day, dbo.Numbers.Number-1, T.Month) AS NewDate
        FROM dbo.Numbers
        WHERE dbo.Numbers.Number <= T.Repeat_Count
    ) AS CA
ORDER BY NewDate;
```

**Result**

```
+----------+------+-------------------------+--------------+--------+-------------------------+
| Property | Item |          Month          | Repeat_Count | Amount |         NewDate         |
+----------+------+-------------------------+--------------+--------+-------------------------+
| A        | Rent | 2016-01-01 00:00:00.000 |            1 |    100 | 2016-01-01 00:00:00.000 |
| A        | Rent | 2016-02-01 00:00:00.000 |            1 |    105 | 2016-02-01 00:00:00.000 |
| A        | Rent | 2016-03-01 00:00:00.000 |            3 |    110 | 2016-03-01 00:00:00.000 |
| A        | Rent | 2016-03-01 00:00:00.000 |            3 |    110 | 2016-03-02 00:00:00.000 |
| A        | Rent | 2016-03-01 00:00:00.000 |            3 |    110 | 2016-03-03 00:00:00.000 |
| A        | Rent | 2016-06-01 00:00:00.000 |            1 |    115 | 2016-06-01 00:00:00.000 |
| A        | Rent | 2016-07-01 00:00:00.000 |            6 |    120 | 2016-07-01 00:00:00.000 |
| A        | Rent | 2016-07-01 00:00:00.000 |            6 |    120 | 2016-07-02 00:00:00.000 |
| A        | Rent | 2016-07-01 00:00:00.000 |            6 |    120 | 2016-07-03 00:00:00.000 |
| A        | Rent | 2016-07-01 00:00:00.000 |            6 |    120 | 2016-07-04 00:00:00.000 |
| A        | Rent | 2016-07-01 00:00:00.000 |            6 |    120 | 2016-07-05 00:00:00.000 |
| A        | Rent | 2016-07-01 00:00:00.000 |            6 |    120 | 2016-07-06 00:00:00.000 |
| A        | Rent | 2017-01-01 00:00:00.000 |            1 |    125 | 2017-01-01 00:00:00.000 |
+----------+------+-------------------------+--------------+--------+-------------------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [Tally Table](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/62867/) to generate the dates:

```
WITH E1(N) AS( -- 10 ^ 1 = 10 rows
    SELECT 1 FROM(VALUES (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1))t(N)
),
E2(N) AS(SELECT 1 FROM E1 a CROSS JOIN E1 b), -- 10 ^ 2 = 100 rows
E4(N) AS(SELECT 1 FROM E2 a CROSS JOIN E2 b), -- 10 ^ 4 = 10,000 rows
CteTally(N) AS(
    SELECT TOP(SELECT MAX(Repeat_Count) FROM tbl) ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY(SELECT NULL))
    FROM E4
)
SELECT
    t.Property,
    t.Item,
    [Month] = DATEADD(MONTH, c.N-1, t.Month),
    t.Amount
FROM tbl t
INNER JOIN CteTally c
    ON c.N <= t.Repeat_Count
ORDER BY t.Property, t.Item, [Month]
```